# Passing non-thread-safe objects through thread-safe containers

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a thread-safe object queue which is designed to model a pipeline of work moving between a chain of threads. In some cases, I want to pass non-thread-safe objects (e.g., `std::vector`s, or other STL containers) as part of these work items.

Now, in the case you have a shared object between threads, there is an obvious problem of load/store ordering in ensuring object consistency. Since the thread-safe queue ensures that only one thread has ownership of the object there is no chance for multiple threads trying to modify or read the object at the same time.. the only possible problem I see is ensuring memory consistency in previously issued loads/stores on the object by previous owner threads.

The queue ensures thread safety by creating a `lock_guard<...>` on queue operations. Wouldn't memory consistency of the object being moved between threads be guaranteed since the memory fencing and synchronization would be taken care by the `lock_guard`?

Part of me wants to ensure I am only passing thread-safe objects between threads, but I feel like this case there should be no problem. Is this true?

Comment: Sounds like a good question for Programmers.SE, FWIW.

Comment: @PreferenceBean I think it's a good and valid question here (not that experienced with SE Programmers though).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It has no code in it, and I'd like to see us send more good content to Programmers so we don't starve it. But I don't disagree.

Comment: @PreferenceBean Not every question at Stack Overflow needs to show detailed code (even if the tags seem to require this). At least some of the best Q&A pairs we can find on SO contain very little code. Sure that is a kind of _"whiteboard drawing and discussion"_ question that would fit for Programmers as well.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I said I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The queue ensures thread safety by creating a lock_guard<...> on queue operations. Wouldn't memory consistency of the object being moved between threads be guaranteed since the memory fencing and synchronization would be taken care by the lock_guard?

Yes.

> Part of me wants to ensure I am only passing thread-safe objects between threads, but I feel like this case there should be no problem. Is this true?

Yes.

This is essentially why `volatile` is inapplicable as a device for concurrent data access in C++; it doesn't solve race conditions and, once you've brought concurrency devices (e.g. mutexes) into the fray to fix that, those are also taking care of the memory consistency issue so there's simply nothing left for `volatile` to do.

Comment: I'd like to add a comment about this: as I'm still learning about multi threading, if you are working on a windows platform look up CRITICAL_SECTION on MSDN and how it works.

Comment: @FrancisCugler No `CRITICAL_SECTION` is way off here. The OP clearly asked about standard c++ `lock_guard`s.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am still trying to get my head around ensuring consistency while maximizing performance with the C++11 memory model. In lock-free programming I am assuming that the same would be true as long as relaxed orderings are avoided with atomic RMWs?

Comment: @0n1: I don't know. I don't know much about this stuff.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I can understand that; but I was just referring to multi-threaded programming in general, and this is one of the methods I use to lock a function or class object to prevent race conditions and bottle necks. I have a custom class object to block threads that does this work for me, all I have to do in an outside class is to include the class header and to declare a static CRITICAL_SECTION and use it in the appropriate section. I also have another class that is a class template which is a VolatileLocker.

Comment: @FrancisCugler: I think you meant deadlocks, not bottlenecks. If you're using critical sections to alleviate bottlenecks then something is very wrong. I know that at least.

Comment: @FrancisCugler 1. It's not portable. 2. That it needs to be static often makes it more of a problem than a benefit in a well OO design.

Comment: @0n1 Things like `std::vectors` can't be made available with `std::atomic`. The RMW operations appear on the thread safe queue right? Thus a `std::mutex` along with a `std::lock_guard` is perfectly sufficient and fine.

Comment: @PreferenceBean you could be correct; as I'm still learning; but I know the classes that I use does help with concurrency and to prevent race conditions meaning that if I'm entering a critical section where I'm either going through a for loop or a while loop or iterating through a container that no other thread can have access until this section of code leaves the critical section.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well I'm not writing code to be cross platform as I'm my directed target audience is windows platform.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I am familiar with the trivial-copy requirement of std::atomic. I just mean in cases where we avoid locks (e.g., std::mutex, std::lock_guard, etc.) as in a lock-free queue.

Answer (score 0):

I use a slightly different method to block threads I do not know if this would help in any way or not but I don't mind sharing what I have to offer different opinions or approaches.

**BlockThread.h**

```
#ifndef BLOCK_THREAD_H
#define BLOCK_THREAD_H

namespace vmk {

class BlockThread sealed {
private:
    CRITICAL_SECTION* m_pCriticalSection;

public:
    explicit BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection );
    ~BlockThread();

private:
    BlockThread( const BlockThread& c ); // Not Implemented
    BlockThread& operator=( const BlockThread& c ); // Not Implemented
    // void swap( BlockThread& other ) throw();

}; // BlockThread

} // namespace vmk

#endif // BLOCK_THREAD_H
```

**BlockThread.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"

namespace vmk {

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// BlockThread()
BlockThread::BlockThread( CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection ) {
    m_pCriticalSection = &criticalSection;
    EnterCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection );
} // BlockThread

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~BlockThread()
BlockThread::~BlockThread() {
    LeaveCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection );
} // ~BlockThread    

} // namespace vmk
```

**VolatileLocker.h**

```
#ifndef VOLATILE_LOCKER_H
#define VOLATILE_LOCKER_H

namespace vmk {

template <typename T>
class VolatileLocker {
private:
    T*                  m_pObject;
    CRITICAL_SECTION*   m_pCriticalSection;

public:
    VolatileLocker( volatile T& objectToLock, CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection );
    ~VolatileLocker();

    T* operator->();

private:
    VolatileLocker( const VolatileLocker& c ); // Not Implemented
    VolatileLocker& operator=( const VolatileLocker& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // VolatileLocker

#include "VolatileLocker.inl"

} // namespace vmk

#endif // VOLATILE_LOCKER_H

// reference: http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184403766
```

**VolatileLocker.inl**

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// VolatileLocker()
// Locks A Volatile Variable So That It Can Be Used Across Multiple Threads Safely
template<typename T>
VolatileLocker<T>::VolatileLocker( volatile T& objectToLock, CRITICAL_SECTION& criticalSection ) :
m_pObject( const_cast<T*>( &objectToLock ) ),
m_pCriticalSection( &criticalSection ) {
    EnterCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection );
} // VolatileLocker

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~VolatileLocker()
template<typename T>
VolatileLocker<T>::~VolatileLocker() {
    LeaveCriticalSection( m_pCriticalSection );
} // ~VolatileLocker

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// operator->()
// Allow The Locked Object To Be Used Like A Pointer
template <typename T>
T* VolatileLocker<T>::operator->() {
    return m_pObject;
} // operator->
```

Here is a class object that uses BlockThread - This class depends on other classes not shown here and I'll only include the parts of this class that uses the BlockThread Object.

**AudioManager.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AudioManager.h"

#include "AudioBuffer.h"
#include "AudioSource.h"
#include "BlockThread.h"
#include "Logger.h"

namespace vmk {

static AudioManager*        s_pAudioManager = nullptr;
static CRITICAL_SECTION     s_csChangeSources;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// AudioManager()
AudioManager::AudioManager() :
Singleton( Singleton::TYPE_AUDIO_MANAGER ) {
    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_csChangeSources );

    if ( !alutInit( NULL, NULL ) ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " ALUT error: " << alutGetErrorString( alutGetError() );
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    alGetError(); // Clear Errors

    alListenerf( AL_GAIN, 1.0f ); // Master Volume
    alListener3f( AL_POSITION, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    alListener3f( AL_VELOCITY, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

    float f6Orient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,   // Forward(X, Y, Z)
                         0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f }; // Up(X,Y,Z)

    alListenerfv( AL_ORIENTATION, f6Orient );
    if ( alGetError() != AL_NO_ERROR ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " Failed to initialize Listener";
        throw ExceptionHandler( strStream );
    }

    s_pAudioManager = this;
} // AudioManager

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~AudioManager()
AudioManager::~AudioManager() {
    s_pAudioManager = nullptr;

    m_mAudioSources.clear();
    m_lAudioBuffers.clear();

    alutExit();

    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_csChangeSources );
} // ~AudioManager

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// get()
AudioManager* const AudioManager::get() {
    if ( nullptr == s_pAudioManager ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " failed, AudioManager has not been constructed yet" ) );
    }
    return s_pAudioManager;
} // get    

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create A Sound Source Using The Passed In Filename. If The File Is Not
// Already Loaded Into A Memory Buffer, Then A New Buffer Is Created.
void AudioManager::createSource( SoundSource eSoundSource, const std::string& strFilename, bool bAttachToListener ) {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_csChangeSources );

    if ( !isAvailable( eSoundSource ) ) {
        return;
    }

    std::shared_ptr<AudioBuffer> pAudioBuffer = nullptr;

    // Check If This File Has Already Been Loaded Into A Buffer
    for ( ListAudioBuffers::iterator itBuffer = m_lAudioBuffers.begin(); itBuffer != m_lAudioBuffers.end(); ++itBuffer ) {
        if ( (*itBuffer)->isThisFile( strFilename ) ) {
            // The Requested File Is Already Loaded Into Memory
            pAudioBuffer = (*itBuffer);
            break;
        }
    }

    try {
        if ( nullptr == pAudioBuffer ) {
            // Need To Load The Desired File Into Memory
            pAudioBuffer.reset( new AudioBuffer( strFilename ) );

            // Store The Buffer
            m_lAudioBuffers.push_back( pAudioBuffer );
        }

        // Create New Source Attached To The Desired Audio Buffer
        m_mAudioSources[eSoundSource] = std::shared_ptr<AudioSource>( new AudioSource( eSoundSource, pAudioBuffer, bAttachToListener ) );

    } catch ( ... ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " failed for SoundSource(" << eSoundSource << ")";
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
    }
} // createSource

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Removes Source From Map And If Buffer Is No Longer Needed,
// It Will Also Be Deleted
void AudioManager::deleteSource( SoundSource eSoundSource ) {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_csChangeSources );

    MapAudioSources::iterator it = m_mAudioSources.find( eSoundSource );
    if ( it == m_mAudioSources.end() ) {
        std::ostringstream strStream;
        strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " could not find SoundSource(" << eSoundSource << ")";
        Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
        return; // Nothing To Delete
    }

    // Get bufferId And Delete Source
    unsigned uBufferId = it->second->getBufferId();
    m_mAudioSources.erase( it );

    // Find Buffer In List
    if ( uBufferId != INVALID_UNSIGNED ) {
        for ( ListAudioBuffers::iterator itBuffer = m_lAudioBuffers.begin(); itBuffer != m_lAudioBuffers.end(); ++itBuffer ) {
            if ( (*itBuffer)->getId() == uBufferId ) {
                if ( (*itBuffer)->getNumberSourcesAttached() < 1 ) {
                    // Buffer No Longer Needed
                    m_lAudioBuffers.erase( itBuffer );
                    return;
                } // If Buffer Not Needed
            } // If Found Buffer
        } // For All Buffers
    } // If Buffer Is Loaded
} // deleteSource

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// getAudioObject()
AudioObject* AudioManager::getAudioObject( SoundSource eSoundSource ) const {
    BlockThread blockThread( s_csChangeSources );

    MapAudioSources::const_iterator it = m_mAudioSources.find( eSoundSource );
    if ( it != m_mAudioSources.cend() ) {
        return it->second.get();
    }

    std::ostringstream strStream;
    strStream << __FUNCTION__ << " SoundSource(" << eSoundSource << ") has not been found";
    Logger::log( strStream, Logger::TYPE_ERROR );
    return nullptr;
} // getAudioObject


} // namespace vmk
```

And the use of a VolatileLocker would be as follows: NOTE: I also have an OpenglThread class object not shown here to allow OpenGL to work with multiple threads.

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "OpenglThread.h"
#include "VolatileLocker.h"

... other class object includes

namespace vmk {

static CRITICAL_SECTION s_criticalSection; 

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Game()
Game::Game() :
Engine( glm::uvec2( 3, 3 ) ),
m_maxSpeechArea( 250, INVALID_UNSIGNED ),
m_eLastSpeechSound( SS_INTRO_SHOT ),
m_eSoundSourceToPlay( SS_INTRO_SHOT ) {
    InitializeCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );

    const glm::uvec2 gamePixelSize = m_pSettings->getGameSize();

    // (0,0) In Top Left Corner Not Bottom Left Which Is The Default
    m_m4Projection = glm::ortho( 0.0f, static_cast<float>( gamePixelSize.x ), static_cast<float>( gamePixelSize.y ), 0.0f, -10.0f, 10.0f );

    // Set Background Color
    glClearColor( 22.0f / 255.0f, 22.0f / 255.0f, 22.0f / 255.0f, 1.0f );

    // Turn Transparencies On
    glEnable( GL_BLEND );

    // Initialize Shaders
    std::string strVertexShader( "Shaders/gui.vert" );
    std::string strFragmentShader( "Shaders/gui.frag" );

    ShaderProgramSettings shaderProgramSettings( P_MAIN, strVertexShader, strFragmentShader );
    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderAttribute( A_POSITION,             AT_FLOAT_VEC2 ), "inPosition" );
    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderAttribute( A_COLOR,                AT_FLOAT_VEC4 ), "inColor" );
    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderAttribute( A_TEXTURE_COORD0,       AT_FLOAT_VEC2 ), "inTextureCoord0" );

    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderUniform( U_MVP_MATRIX,             UT_FLOAT_MAT4 ), "modelViewProjectionMatrix" );
    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderUniform( U_TEXTURE0_SAMPLER_2D,    UT_SAMPLER_2D ), "texture0Sampler2d" ); 
    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderUniform( U_USING_TEXTURE,          UT_BOOL ),       "usingTexture" );  
    shaderProgramSettings.addVariable( ShaderUniform( U_ALPHA,                  UT_FLOAT ),      "inAlpha" );

    m_pShaderManager->create( shaderProgramSettings );
    m_pShaderManager->enable( P_MAIN );

    m_pBatchManager.reset( new BatchManager( 10, 10000 ) );

    // Must Be Called Before Any GuiElements Are Loaded
    GuiElement::initialize();   

    // Load Game Logo - Title Screen
    m_pTitleScreen = new GuiScreen( std::string( "TitleScreen" ) );

    TextureFileReader titleTextureFileReader( "Assets/images/titleScreen.png" );
    m_titleTextureInfo =  titleTextureFileReader.getOrCreateTextureInfo( TextureInfo::FILTER_NONE, false, false );

    // Start Worker Thread
    _beginthread( loadAssets, 0, this );

    // Game Logo
    GuiLayoutAbsolute* pTitleCoverLayout = new GuiLayoutAbsolute( glm::ivec2(), Gui::LEFT, m_pSettings->getGameSize(), "title cover" );
    pTitleCoverLayout->setColor( glm::vec4( 0.0862745, 0.0862745, 0.0862745, 1.0 ) );
    m_pTitleScreen->addChild( pTitleCoverLayout );

    m_pTitleLayout = new GuiLayoutAbsolute( glm::ivec2( 0, 200 ), Gui::LEFT, glm::uvec2( 955, 400 ), "title" );
    m_pTitleLayout->setBackgroundImage( m_titleTextureInfo, glm::uvec2( 0, 359 ), glm::uvec2( 955, 400 ) );
    m_pTitleLayout->changePriority( 1 );
    m_pTitleScreen->addChild( m_pTitleLayout );

    // Flying Bullet
    m_pFlyingBulletLayout = new GuiLayoutAbsolute( glm::ivec2( 40, -100 ), "flying bullet" );
    m_pTitleLayout->addChild( m_pFlyingBulletLayout );

    // Intro Sound Effect
    m_pAudioManager->createSource( SS_INTRO_SHOT, "Assets/audio/introShot.ogg" );
    m_pAudioManager->play( SS_INTRO_SHOT );

    // Set Timer For How Long Title Screen Should Be Visible
    m_pAnimationManager->addFunction( 5.0, Animation::LINEAR, splashScreenUpdate, this, splashScreenDone, this );

    /*
    int debugLogging = m_pSettings->getDebugLogging() | Settings::DEBUG_RENDER;
    m_pSettings->setDebugLogging( debugLogging );
    */

} // Game

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// ~Game()
Game::~Game() { 
    DeleteCriticalSection( &s_criticalSection );
} // ~Game


// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// splashScreenDone()
// Defined Outside Of Game But Is Declared As A Friend Function To Game And It Utilizes The VolatileLocker
void splashScreenDone( void* pParameter ) {
    Game* pGame = reinterpret_cast<Game*>( pParameter );
    if ( nullptr == pGame ) {
        throw ExceptionHandler( __FUNCTION__ + std::string( " Invalid pParameter passed in" ) );
    }

    VolatileLocker<GameState>( pGame->m_gameState, s_criticalSection )->timerDone();

    if ( VolatileLocker<GameState>( pGame->m_gameState, s_criticalSection )->is( GameState::PLAYING ) ) {
        pGame->m_pAudioManager->play( SS_CHOOSE_LETTER );
    }

} // splashScreenDone

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// keyboardInput()
// A Member Function Of Game That Utilizes The VolatileLocker
void Game::keyboardInput( unsigned vkCode, bool isPressed ) {
    if ( isPressed || VolatileLocker<GameState>( m_gameState, s_criticalSection )->isSplashScreen() ) {
        // Wait For Splash Screen To Be Finished
        // Only React To Key Release Events
        return;
    }

    static unsigned lastKey = 0;

    if ( (VK_ESCAPE == lastKey && VK_ESCAPE == vkCode) ||
        (VK_ESCAPE == vkCode && m_bGameOver) ) {
        // TODO: Show Credits

        quitGame( nullptr, nullptr );
        return;
    }
    lastKey = vkCode;

    if ( m_bGameOver ) {
        if ( VK_SPACE == vkCode ) {
            restart();
        }
        return;
    }

    if ( VK_ESCAPE == vkCode ) {
        updateSpeech( "To qui the game, press ESC again.", COLOR_YELLOW );
        speak( SS_QUIT_GAME );

    } else if ( vkCode >= VK_KEYA && vkCode <= VK_KEYZ ) {
        // Play Sound
        m_pAudioManager->play( SS_GUN_SHOT );

        updatePuzzle( static_cast<char>( vkCode ) );

        // Show Gun Fire & Start Timer To Reset Graphics Back To Normal
        showGunFire( true );
        m_pAnimationManager->addTimer( 0.2, resetGunGraphics, this );

    } else {
        updateSpeech( "Choose a letter." );
        speak( SS_CHOOSE_LETTER );
    }

} // keyboardInput

} // namespace vmk
```

Now I know the OP mentioned about working in a Thread Pool or Queue, but I think the overall concept of being able to lock threads for safety reasons can be shown here as well. This may also serve as a guide to anyone who may read this.